# Ansible: Error drop multiples databases MySQL

Tags: mysql, automation, ansible

I want to drop multiples databases (MySQL) on ansible :

```
- name: Drop databases on Ansible
  local_action: mysql_db  name= {{ item.name }}  state=absent
    with_items:
      - { name: dba }
      - { name: dbb }
      - { name: dbc }
       ...
```

I have this ERROR :

```
ERROR! Syntax Error while loading YAML.

The error appears to have been in '/etc/ansible/roles/drop-db/tasks/main.yml': line 7, column 15, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

  local_action: mysql_db  name= {{ item.name }}  state=absent
    with_items:
              ^ here
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fix your indentation!

And don't add spaces between `=` and the value when using Ansible's notation.

```
- name: Drop databases on Ansible
  local_action: mysql_db  name={{ item.name }}  state=absent
  with_items:
    - { name: dba }
    - { name: dbb }
    - { name: dbc }
    ...
```